# Listview selecteditem in xamarin

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, selecteditem

I have a listview that is populated with a list of terms from ItemsSource. The .Name property is the text shown on the listview. I am trying to save the .Id int property to a variable so that I can access it from another form. Essentially I want it so that when a user clicks on an item on the list it will open a form and populate it with the instance of the list associated with the item tapped.

If the listview is populated with Book1, Book2, Book3, and Book4 with Ids of 1, 2, 3, and 4 then if the user taps Book2 I want the SelectedBook variable to be set to the .Id property of 2. Then when another form will be opened and this form will pull the appropriate book instance from the sqlite database and populate the fields with that book's information.

I have been trying to do so with the ItemSelected property of the ListView but have been getting this error "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".

Here is the code that I used:

```
        public void OnSelectedItem(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Book myBook = sender as Term;
        App.BookRep.SelectedBook = myBook.Id;
}
```

I originally had the listview populated with buttons (that is my preference) but the SelectedItem property of ListView didn't seem to be utilized when I did this. I tried using the Clicked property of Button but couldn't find a way to obtain the Id for the selected book in this way. Am I doing something incorrectly or is there a better way to go about doing this?

Comment: You can get the selected item from the EventArgs property which you can then cast to your model Book and get the ID property from there.

Comment: To clarify, you can get the SelectedItem from the args argument. Casting it to the Book model should give you the binding for the selected viewcell.

Comment: @SparshaBhattarai thank you for the reply! I have been trying different combinations of implementing this but have not been able to get it tow ork. How would you go about casting the args to the book model?

Comment: Just do the cast you've done with sender but instead with the selecteditem. var curItem = args.SelectedItem as Book; and then use the curItem.ID property for the rest.

Answer (score 2):

> I originally had the listview populated with buttons (that is my preference) but the SelectedItem property of ListView didn't seem to be utilized when I did this.

There are two solution to get what you want:

**Solution One:** Should use `SelectedItemChangedEventArgs` to get `SelectedItem`

```
public void OnSelectedItem(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs args)
{
    Book myBook = (Book)args.SelectedItem;
    App.BookRep.SelectedBook = myBook.Id;
}
```

**Solution Two:**

```
public void OnSelectedItem(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Book myBook = ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem as Book;
    App.BookRep.SelectedBook = myBook.Id;
}
```

> I tried using the Clicked property of Button but couldn't find a way to obtain the Id for the selected book in this way.

**Solution Three:**

If using Button click event to do , add Button in Xaml:

```
<Button Text="Click" HorizontalOptions="End" Clicked="OnClicked" />
```

`OnClicked` method is follow:

```
void OnClicked(Object sender, MyEventArgs args)
{
   Button btn = sender as Button;
   Book myBook = btn.BindingContext as Book;
   App.BookRep.SelectedBook = myBook.Id;
}
```

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

If happen this error, check listview whether has some elements not used.Suggest that removing all controls from ListView, then check the select event can work.If not solved, you can show code of **ListView.ItemTemplate**,I will check that.

Answer (score 0):

sender is the control that fired the event, not the data item

```
public void OnSelectedItem(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Book myBook = (Book)args.SelectedItem;
    App.BookRep.SelectedBook = myBook.Id;
}
```